# looping through an array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an array of textarea values and then loop through them.

Here is a jsFiddle that I am trying to get this to work in:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxkHZ/1/

When I run it, nothing happens.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var textArray = [];
$('[class=objectives]').each(function (i) {
     textArray.push($(this).val());
});

for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
     console.log(textArray[i].value);
}
```

Comment: Just change to `console.log(textArray[i]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `value` property in each element, you can simply do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
     console.log(textArray[i]);
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kxkHZ/7/)** - *Note: jQuery wasn't originally included*

Comment: There is a good practise to store array length in a variable, and then use it in for loop

Comment: You mean `for (var i=0, n=textArray.length; i<n; i++)` ?

Comment: for some reason it doesn't show up in my firebug console when I run it in jsfiddle...

Comment: @999cm999 - http://jsfiddle.net/kxkHZ/7/ <- This does print four strings in the console.

Answer (score 4):

You are pushing the value of the element into the array, you do not need to call `value` on it again.  Just access the string itself:

`console.log(textArray[i]);`

Answer (score 3):

Working `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/kxkHZ/11/

```
for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
    // textArray[i] itself is the value so textArray[i].value is incorrect 
    console.log(textArray[i]); 
}
```

You forgot to include jquery -

You should have got an error `$` is not defined.

Comment: Still doesn't work. You wind up writing 'undefined' to the console 4 times.